# Different NavigationItem

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

`VC1` is embedded in a `NavigationController`. In `VC1` I'm setting up a new `VC2` and embed it in a new `NavigationController`. I want to add a button while setting up `VC2` so I access `navigationItem`, but the button isn't showing up. I've checked the `navigationItem` in `VC1` and `VC2` and they have the same memory address. What am I doing wrong?

```
class VC1: UIViewController {

    let button = UIButton()

    func changeView() {
        let controller = VC2()
        let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)

        button.sizeToFit()

        navigation.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

        print("VC1: ", Unmanaged.passUnretained(navigation.navigationItem))

        navigationController?.pushViewController(navigation, animated: true)
    }
}

class VC2: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super. viewDidAppear(animated)

        print("VC2: ", Unmanaged.passUnretained(navigationItem)) // same memory
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set the `navigationItem` of the navigation controller. Set it on the view controller. The navigation controller shows the nav items from the top view controller in its stack.

So the line:

```
navigation.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

should be:

```
controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

Besides this, your print statements are correct. In `VC1` you print the nav controller's navigation item. Since `VC2` is the top view controller, it will show the navigation item of `VC2`.

Comment: Thanks!. Strange I would have thought `navigation.navigationItem` would print the one "linked" to `navigation`.

Comment: It does. It's linked to the `navigationItem` of its top view controller.